# CSS - Select all childs except the first

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 1</p>
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 2, paragraph 1</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Using CSS, is it possible to select all elements `<p>`, except the first, for each element `.chapter` and `.section`? For instance, I'd like to select `<p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>`, `<p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>`, `<p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>`, `<p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>`, and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to miss `<p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include it in my list of examples. Thank you to pointing that out @chipChocolate.py

Comment: Then my answer was correct and I deleted it coz you forgot to mention that lol

Comment: See my comment to your response bellow @chipChocolate.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `:first-of-type` combined with the `:not`

```css
.chapter > p:not(:first-of-type),
.section > p:not(:first-of-type){
  color:#ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 1</p>
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 2, paragraph 1</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 3</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 4</p>
     </div>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(:first-child)`

```css
.chapter p:not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 1</p>
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 2, paragraph 1</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One further approach, as part of a drive of completism, perpaps:

```css
.chapter p:first-child ~ p {
  color: red;
}

.chapter {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.section {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 1</p>
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 2, paragraph 1</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) <sup>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)</sup>.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight on the subject. @David Thomas Even tough your suggestion works on this snippet, it does not work on my .css file.

Comment: Then there's a unspecified difference between your implementation and the one you posted in your question, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you honestly expect me to try and debug your HTML and CSS from a screenshot of the Web Inspector? Really..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child

```css
<style>
 .chapter p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
 }
 .section p:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 1</p>
     <p>chapter 1, paragraph 2</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 1, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="chapter"> 
     <p>chapter 2, paragraph 1</p>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 1, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="section">
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 1</p>
          <p>chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use element+element selector for your task and  here is example.

```
.chapter p + p,
.section p + p {  };
```

It will select all next elements after first p tag.